# Wearable ChannelClient sendFile package variables with a png file?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to use the [ChannelClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelClient) to send data to a wearable, but I need to send an image along with data (int, boolean, and text). From [this article](https://medium.com/@shoaibsaikat/using-android-channelclient-f5b4fd346374), ChannelClient has two ways of transferring data. One is sending stream, another is sending data through file ([code here](https://github.com/shoaibsaikat/Android-Channel-Client-File-Transfer)).

Since the png is a file, I need to use file, but how do I add data to a file, send it through and unpack it? Here is what the code looks like now:

**Phone**

```
 File file = new File("/data/user/0/com.xxx.yyy/files/test.png");
 channelClient.sendFile(channel, Uri.fromFile(file)).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
           Log.d(TAG, "channelTest.sendFile.onComplete: ");
      }
 });
```

**Wearable**

```
@Override
public void onChannelOpened(@NonNull ChannelClient.Channel channel) {
    super.onChannelOpened(channel);

    Log.d(TAG, "onChannelOpened: node=" + channel.getNodeId() + "; path=" + channel.getPath() + ";");

    File outFile  = new File((getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("test.png").getPath()));
    final Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);

    Wearable.getChannelClient(getApplicationContext()).receiveFile(channel, fileUri, false);
    Wearable.getChannelClient(getApplicationContext()).registerChannelCallback(new ChannelClient.ChannelCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onInputClosed(@NonNull ChannelClient.Channel channel, int i, int i1) {
            super.onInputClosed(channel, i, i1);
            Log.d(TAG, "onInputClosed: ");

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath());

            Wearable.getChannelClient(getApplicationContext()).close(channel);
        }
    });
    
}
```

Comment: You can't reuse the ChannelClient for sending other data after using it for a file.  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelClient
Probably slower than the file implementation by Play Services, but you could possibly read and write the data yourself, possibly as protobuf encoded with a byte array for the file contents. Or roll your own writing the filelength | filedata | int | boolean | string length | stringdata

Comment: That's why I was thinking to package up all the data into the file and sending it over. The uber file would create data + the the file. Perhaps stream would be best.